# Как изменить кодировку?

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка, php

Ребята, выручайте. Как сменить кодировку: http://biblog.h1.ru/ (да простят меня модераторы), полдня маюсь, никак не могу сменить, пробовал перекодировать файлы, не получается. Что мне делать?

ЗЫ сайт на CMS Nanote.

Comment: А какой хостер? На ру-центре можно сменить кодировку сайта в панели управления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нужно указать кодировку в файле .htaccess **AddDefaultCharset utf-8**
2. Изменить кодировку в dreamweaver или notepad++(без bom)
3. В самом начале в php файле добавить строчку **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');**
    В общем как то так.

Answer (score 0):

У вас UTF-8.

1. Открываете файл через блокнот.
2. Файл => сохранить как.
3. В пункте Кодировка по умолчанию (ANSI) ставите UTF-8.
4. Сохраняете в новой кодировке и будет вам счастье. ))

И так каждый публичный файл. ))

Comment: Неа, не будет, я же говорил, что файлы перекодировал, а потом сайт весь полетел, так как там сериализация стоит, и не пашет из-за этого ничего.

Comment: я только что твою страницу в браузере перекодировал и прочитал все на русском. )) По другому UTF-8 не обработать. Ты index файл так попробуй и все увидишь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в far открыть страничку и включить кодировку 65001. Это shift+f8. У меня так было, очень долго мучилась. Я, конечно, не гарантирую, но попытка - не пытка.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно помогло:
Вставьте в файл ".htaccess", тот что был "rename.htaccess" из корневого каталога строку:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Браузеры очень капризны и автоматически определяют кодировку по кодировке первого символа пришедшего с сервера, даже если вся страница и значение `<title>` написаны на указанной кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток!
Тоже была такая проблема, решил с андроида:
Скачал приложение TurboEditor, зашел в настройки, выставил код, мне нужно было из win1251 в utf8, в настройках выставил utf8, открыл свой index.php с помощью данного приложения, ничего не менял, Просто сохранил свой Индекс поновой и всё, Он стал в кодировке utf8.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните, какое отношение имеет ваш ответ к теме вопроса, android  в метках вроде нет?