# Перевод сайта из одной кодировки в другую

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка, php, mysql

Необходимо перевести сайт из CP1251 в UTF-8. Перевёл все странички, сделал:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

непосредственно из php-скрипта для всех таблиц.

Далее дописал строчку:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $link);
```

в функцию, которая коннектит к БД.

Теперь вопрос - правильно ли так сделать?

Как я понял, содержимое таблиц не поменялось, у них только стало сравнение `utf8_general_ci` вместо `cp1251_general_ci`. Если не писать `SET NAMES utf8`, то идут кракозябры. Будут ли какие-то проблемы из-за этого когда-нибудь, и не является ли такое решение неоптимальным? И если следует перевести БД в UTF-8, то можно ли это сделать из php-скрипта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите пожалуйста мой ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/28140/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83).
Данные действия нужно сделать со всеми файлами, которые участвуют в генерации кода.

Comment: Ну 2-ой и 3-ий пункт я сделал конечно же, первый не делал, но он в духе 3-его. Но вопрос не об этом вообще, вопрос про mysql. Правилно ли я сделал и если нет, то как лучше сделать и, иначе говоря, оптимален ли такой способ перевода или это ресурсозатратно. Мои вопросы в последних двух абзацах, в настоящее время сайт работает абсолютно корректно в utf-8.

Comment: По поводу MySQL вы всё сделали правильно.